# Can I keep on running Office 2016 preview after official release

Tags: microsoft-office, preview, microsoft-office-2016

I'd like to install Microsoft office preview on my windows 10 running computer.Its public preview version is still available and free.I haven't try out any office preview before .On Microsoft's official website says

> You will be on the Office 2016 Preview track until you uninstall the
>   Office 2016 Preview or until Office 2016 is released.

I find this explanation a bit vague.I want to ask , what would happen to the installed office preview, if I won't uninstall it after Microsoft releases its stable version.Would the program lock itself or something?

Any experience from previous office previews?

Comment: I got locked out of preview version of office 2013 after the original one was released. Couldn't even reinstall on a clean virtual machine disconnected from outside world. May be some time period is hard coded to the license or program.

Comment: The Office 2016 Preview will expire.  You can continue to use it until such time.  The explanation seems clear enough, the expiration date for the Office 2016 preview, likely will be Oct 22 2016.